# to get n maximum numbers from python dataframe column

Tags: pandas, max

```
# to get 3 largest numbers from column duration with all duplicates
import pandas as pd
technologies =  "A B C D E F G H I J".split()
duration     = [88,70,50,87,77,88,77,88,1,87]
columns      = ['technologies','duration']
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(technologies,duration)), columns=columns)

print(df.nlargest(3, 'duration',keep = "all"))
```

output:

```
      technologies  duration
0            A        88
5            F        88
7            H        88
```

Desired output:

```
      technologies  duration
0            A        88
5            F        88
7            H        88
3            D        87
9            J        87
4            E        77
6            G        77
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`rank`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html) to get all values which match the 3 largest durations:

```py
out = (df[df['duration'].rank(method='dense', ascending=False) <= 3]
    .sort_values('duration', ascending=False)
)
```

Output:

```
  technologies  duration
0            A        88
5            F        88
7            H        88
3            D        87
9            J        87
4            E        77
6            G        77
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) with filter top 3 unique values by [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) and [`Series.unique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stabltransfe/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html):

```
top = (df.sort_values('duration', ascending=False)
         .pipe(lambda x: x[x['duration'].isin(x['duration'].unique()[:3])]))
print (top)
  technologies  duration
0            A        88
5            F        88
7            H        88
3            D        87
9            J        87
4            E        77
6            G        77
```

Alternative:

```
top = df.sort_values('duration', ascending=False)
top = top[top['duration'].isin(top['duration'].unique()[:3])]
```